# How are you coping up with Bigquery especially when you came from traditional RDMS background like Oracle/Mysql?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to BQ. I have a table with around 200 columns, when i wanted to get DDL of this table there is no ready-made option available. CATS is not always desirable.. some times we dont have a refernce table to create with CATS, some times we just wanted a simple DDL statement to recreate a table.
I wanted to edit a schema of bigquery with changes to mode.. previous mode is nullable now its required.. (already loaded columns has this column loaded with non-null values till now)

Looking at all these scenarios and the lengthy solution provided from Google documentation, and also no direct solution interms of SQL statements rather some API calls/UI/Scripts etc. I feel not impressed with Bigquery with many limitations. And the Web UI from Google Bigquery is so small that you need to scroll lot many times to see the query as a whole. and many other Web UI issues as you know.
Just wanted to know how you are all handling/coping up with BQ.

Comment: BigQuery is engineered for large data scale up to exabytes, so the trivial RDBMS solutions might not work. You need to shift your mindset tovards arhitecting the changes as it was trillions of entries in MySQL. BQ is 10 years old, and it's used extensively on the market. It's awesome at superlative scale.

Comment: Agree with @Pentium10. BigQuery allows you to perform SQL standard query but it's not a relational and transactional database, i.e. you don't have any foreign key and thus schema consistency; and you haven't transaction management with rollback possible. BigQuery is a datawarehouse and it is "slow" to start a query (about 1s) compare to RDBMS which answer in millis. However, BigQuery can process Tb or Pb of data, with aggregations, transformation, even ML prediction, in seconds!

Comment: Completely agree with you @Pentium10 and guillaume, But my concern is GCP might have given some simple ways to create a DDL statement out of a existing table, a workbench tool like Toad/sql developer etc to work with querying, as working on a browser tab with very limited viewing space is making the job hard. Also to change the schema when they can able to provide a solution in json style, there is a good chance theat they can be able to provide a SQL solution for the same. some thoughts.. Thanks for your replies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to elaborate a little bit more to @Pentium10 and @guillaume blaquiere comments.

BigQuery is a serverless, highly scalable data warehouse that comes with a built-in query engine, which is capable of running SQL queries on terabytes of data in a matter of seconds, and petabytes in only minutes. You get this performance without having to manage any infrastructure.

BigQuery is based on Google's column based data processing technology called `dremel` and is able to run queries against up to 20 different data sources and 200GB of data concurrently. Prediction API allows users to create and train a model hosted within Google’s system. The API recognizes historical patterns to make predictions about patterns in new data.

BigQuery is unlike anything that has been used as a big data tool. Nothing seems to compare to the speed and the amount of data that can be fitted into BigQuery. Data views are possible and recommended with basic data visualization tools.

This product typically comes at the end of the Big Data pipeline. It is not a replacement for existing technologies but it complements them. Real-time streams representing sensor data, web server logs or social media graphs can be ingested into BigQuery to be queried in real time. After running the ETL jobs on traditional RDBMS, the resultant data set can be stored in BigQuery. Data can be ingested from the data sets stored in Google Cloud Storage, through direct file import or through streaming data

I recommend you to have a look for `Google BigQuery: The Definitive Guide: Data Warehousing, Analytics, and Machine Learning at Scale` book about BigQuery that includes walkthrough on how to use the service and a deep dive of how it works.

More than that, I found really interesting [article](https://martechseries.com/mts-insights/guest-authors/7-gotchas-data-engineers-new-google-bigquery/) for Data Engineers new to BigQuery, where you can find consideration regarding DDL and UI and best practices on [Medium](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-best-practices-9452c294c9d9).

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.